# Save image temporarily using io for pre-processing without using disk resources

Tags: python, django, io

My current project requires that i deal with uploaded files(mostly images) for pre-processing before i save them.

So far my main method has been to upload to Amazon s3 then download and work on them.

This is not ideal because i do not really need to save the uploaded image but rather the final product.

Is it possible to use the io module to save the Django InMemoryUploadedFile as bytes and somehow return an actual image from it? My attempts so far have failed miserably. Maybe i do not necessarily understand the io module well.

```
def temp_file(f):
    """ 
    CREATES TEMP FILE THAT DOES NOT GET UPLOADED
    f is the InMemoryUploadedFile of image
    """
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    buffer.write(f.read())
    image = buffer.read()
    buffer.close()
    img = Image.open(image)
    return img
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about your attempts (including code) and what has failed so far? It's easier to answer from a code snippet than just a formal question. `io` may not even be needed if you use `ContentFile`.

Comment: I will be dealing with images and pdfs a lot. There is an example here( under "Complex PDFs") of how to deal with complex pdf file in django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/outputting-pdf/.  I am trying to replicate the same example for images.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate an image you've uploaded in a PDF, you may want this kind of thing:

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

def upload_view(request):
    image = request.FILES['image']
    imagebuffer = BytesIO()
    for chunk in image.chunks():
        imagebuffer.write(chunk)
    image = Image.open(imagebuffer)
    imagebuffer.close()
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    c = canvas.Canvas(response)
    c.drawImage(image, x, y)
    ...
```

Comment: I actually wanted one for images only. Quick question though: If i had 1000 users doing this at the same time, will it make my server slower as everything is on memory? As opposed to saving images on a disk?

Comment: With the kind of code I've written above, the image will only stay in memory from the HTTP request to the rendering of the response. It shouldn't be hitting the memory much more than disk based images, as these would have to be transferred via the memory anyway when reading from POST.files and then when writing to the HTTP response. If what you want is to keep images in memory for longer than the POST to response, then you need to use Django's caching framework.

Answer (score 0):

`Image.open()` expects a filename or a file like object (with `read()`, `seek()`, and `tell()` methods). So you have to give the `buffer` object to `Image.open()`. Not closed and rewinded to the beginning.

```
def temp_file(f):
    return Image.open(io.BytesIO(f.read()))
```